# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32'). Recommendation system django

Tags: python, django, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

Request Method: GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/carreviews/recommendation/ Django Version:    2.0.2 Exception Type:   ValueError Exception Value:  Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

Here my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Review, Car

from .form import ReviewForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime

from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

def review_list(request):
    latest_review_list = Review.objects.order_by('')[:9]
    context = {'latest review_list': latest_review_list}
    return render(request,'review_list.html', context)

def review_detail(request,pk):
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, id=pk)
    return render(request,'review_detail.html',{'review': review})

def car_list(request):
    car_list = Car.objects.order_by('-title')[:20]
    context = {'car_list': car_list}
    return render(request,'car_list.html', context)

def car_detail(request,pk):
    car = get_object_or_404(Car, id=pk)
    form = ReviewForm()
    return render(request,'car_detail.html', {'car': car})

def add_review(request, pk):
    car = get_object_or_404(Car, id=pk)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        user_name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
        review = Review()
        review.car = car
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.rating = rating
        review.comment = comment
        review.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('car_detail', args=(car.id,)))
    return render(request, 'car_detail.html', {'car': car, 'form': form})

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name ='registration/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

def get_suggestions(request):
    num_reviews = Review.objects.count()
    all_user_names = list(map(lambda x: x.id, User.objects.only("id")))
    all_car_ids = set(map(lambda x: x.car.id, Review.objects.only("car")))
    num_users = len(list(all_user_names))
    carRatings_m = sp.sparse.dok_matrix((num_users, max(all_car_ids)+1), dtype=np.float32)

    for i in range(num_users):
        user_reviews = Review.objects.filter(user_id=all_user_names[i])
        for user_review in user_reviews:
            carRatings_m[i, user_review.car.id] = user_review.rating
    carRatings = carRatings_m.transpose()
    coo = carRatings.tocoo(copy=False)
    df=pd.DataFrame({'cars': coo.row, 'users': coo.col, 'rating': coo.data}
    )[['cars', 'users', 'rating']].sort_values(['cars', 'users']
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
    mo = df.pivot_table (index=['cars'], columns=['users'],values='rating')
    mo.replace({np.nan: 0}, regex=True, inplace= True)
    model_knn = NearestNeighbors(algorith m='brute', metric='cosine', n_neighbors= 7)
    model_knn.fit(mo.values)
    distance, indices = model_knn.kneighbors(mo.iloc[100,:].reshape(1, -1), return_distance=True)
    context = list(map(lambda x: Car.objects.get(id=indices.flatten()[x] ),range(0,len(distance.flatten()))))
    return render(request, 'get_suggestions.html',{'context': context})
```

heres my view.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.db.models import Avg
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Car(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def average_rating(self):
        return self.review_set.aggregate(Avg('rating'))
        return {'rating_avg'}
         #return self.review_set.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating_avg']

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.title

class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1,'1'),
        (2,'2'),
        (3,'3'),
        (4,'4'),
        (5,'5'),
        )


    car = models.ForeignKey('car', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='user')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating =models.FloatField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=None,null=True, blank=True)
```

get_suggestions.html

```
{% extends 'car_list.html' %}

{% block title %}
<h2>Recommendation for {{ username }}</h2>

<p> {{ context }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

I don't know where it was wrong and how to do it.. I'm new to python and django